# How are the engineer's ships made in such a way that they have rubble debris throughout?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

I've only watched Prometheus once, but I believe the tunnels in the ancient Engineer's ship were full of debris that looked a lot like rock fragments -- and not like chunks of metal.  And, IIRC in Alien the ship was fairly clean inside...

Why was the ship in Prometheus full of rubble?  Is there any in-universe explanation of the construction of these ships that could explain it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Short answer: the ship tunnels are not full of debris.

The walls are markedly different inside the ship than in the rest of the compound. Where we see rubble the walls are carved out of stone, albeit in a very similar style to the walls of the ship. The ship walls however are much more ornate and apparently made out of metal or another manufactured substance, not carved from rock.

The majority of the structure mapped is NOT the ship, but rather a huge complex. The ship is at the end of the long tunnel leading away from the complex towards where Prometheus landed.

Here is a still of the holomap of the base. Note the long tunnel on the right, this leads to the alien ship.

[image: Holographic Map of Engineer Base]

Here is the holograph of the alien ship. You'll notice it is not actually replicated/present in the previous image, though there is consistently similar style of curvature...

[image: Holographic Map of Engineer Spaceship]

Do keep in mind that these holomaps are NOT at the same scale!

Comment: But when the captain sees the holograph of the whole ship produced by the pups, did it show other tunnels outside the ship?  Because IIRC it showed only the ship.

Comment: There are several different holographic views produced by the puppies. The main one is the complex/base but NOT the ship. The other is zoomed in on JUST the ship and not showing the complex.

Comment: EXCELLENT!!!!!!